# How to view AD event logs?

Tags: active-directory, google-cloud-platform

Seeing if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Seeing where to obtain Active directory logs with in the GCP console. We have a one way trust setup but not seeing ability to get event logs, audit logs etc.

Is there something that needs to be enabled?

Comment: Thanks, but does anyone have directions on how to view Googles AD platform logs?

Answer (score 0):

There's documentation on GCP site regarding

> [Cloud Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit)
> This explains how to view events in [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/binary-authorization/docs/viewing-audit-logs)
> As well as what roles and how to enable [Audit Logging](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/audit-logging)

I think you can use this as a guide to find the [AD Logs](https://cloud.google.com/managed-microsoft-ad/docs/using-ad-audit-logs)